# NSIS script failed - invalid verbose level

Tags: windows, listview, nsis

I try to create NSIS installer with ListView ([downloaded here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Header_file_for_Listview#Header_file_for_creating_Listview_control)). However after script running I got failure message:

```
!verbose: Invalid verbose level
Error in macro __NSD_LV_InsertColumn_Call on macroline 2
Error in script "E:\Data\installer.nsi" on line 35 -- aborting creation process
```

CommCtrl.nsh was copied to NSIS Include folder. Is there necessary any header file or plugin? Could anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a bug in that 3rd-party header file.

Try something like this:

```
!include "CommCtrl.nsh"
!ifndef _COMMCTRL_NSH_VERBOSE
!define _COMMCTRL_NSH_VERBOSE ${_COMMCTRL_VERBOSE} 
!endif
```